# Mudar cor ListView ao selecionar

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Como posso mudar a cor de um listView ao selecionar?

*abaixo segue como está o metedo em meu projeto:*

```
listDebitosPendentes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                       Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetalhesDebitosActivity.class);

                      //Passa para a activity o id no banco de dados
                       intent.putExtra("ID", id);
                       startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

*Layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/color_list"
    android:weightSum="1">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/edtPesquisa"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="Pesquisa rápida"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,NestedWeights,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listDebitosPendentes"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        tools:ignore="NestedScrolling"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*drawable*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Você quer que mude de cor quando o item estiver "clicado"?

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni, isso, quero que mude ao clicar. e depois volte ao padrão.

Comment: Veja se te atende. Insera `listDebitosPendentes.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);` dentro do `onItemClick`.

Comment: @RodrigoPaixão, dessa forma não. Pois ele pintou toda  a lista e e ela não volta ao padrão.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar um `selector` para o item do listview:

Na pasta `drawable` do projeto crie um novo "drawable resource file", por exemplo, vamos chamar de `exemplo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/azul" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Dentro da pasta `values` crie um xml chamado `colors.xml` se não existir

E insira a cor

```
<color name="azul">#6EA6EC</color>
```

No xml do layout do ITEM, defina a propriedade `backgroud`,  por exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/exemplo">

//..itens

</LinearLayout>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas dessa forma, ele vai colorir toda a lista, preciso que o item fique colorido apenas quando for clicado, depois ele volte ao normal.

Comment: Não vai color toda lista, vai colorir apenas o item que for clicado.

Comment: No código java não preciso adicionar nada?

Comment: Não precisa alterar o java.

Comment: Deixando como disse não LinearLayout, ele não mudou a cor quando precionei no item do listView, coloquei no background para testar tbm, ai ele coloriu toda a lista.

Comment: Você colocou o backgroud no xml do item que você infla no seu listview?

Comment: Eu adicionei o código do layout na pergunta, mas o drawable

Comment: Inserir uma imagem para ver se é o que você deseja

Comment: Isso, é exatamente isso que preciso.

Comment: Faço exatamente o que coloquei na resposta, pode ser algum código seu que faz selecionar toda listview, tenta criar uma outra lista do zero para testar.